# How do you insert data from the user into the file with the most optimal using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files

I’m newbies, I learned Python 2 days ago.

I want to check it has been successfully inserted into the text file?

May I ask you: The way I wrote has the most optimal?

[image]

Note:

- I search google to see the example and follow them.
- My English is not good, please sympathize with me.

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to do what you are describing, however I do not see why you would need to check if the write was successful as Python will tell you if an error occurs. Other than that your code seems to work fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for your opinion. I think I can handle the error issue if it occurs because I will use a try-catch to handle it. I am most concerned about the insert successfully and the way I write the script check inserted successfully with text file right or not? and most optimal? because everything I'm looking for in Google and Stackoverflow and W3school, etc, and I do not see the specific standards for the way the script. When I walk around on Google, I can see a lot of examples with Java (very much). From there I can see many ways of writing another and reinforce knowledge.

Comment: and with Python, I don't see many examples handle with file or OOP. It just introduces in general.

Answer (score 0):

Provided the nameUser-ageUser pairs are unique (i.e. 'Bob 35' appears max. 1 time in the text file), you can use ".find()".

```
nameUser= 'Bob'
ageUser='35'

with open('file.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write('{} {} \n'.format(nameUser, ageUser))


if (open('file.txt', 'r').read().find('{} {} \n'.format(nameUser, ageUser))) != -1:
    print("success!")
```

Comment: what if there was an old record with the same name and age?

Comment: good point, I assumed the name-age pairs would be unique. I'll add an edit to clarify.

Comment: another note is that this code will not 'append' to the file, it'll clear it's content first and then write in it, you should change the file mode from `w` to `a` so it appends to the file